# How to put a mat-form-field next to a h1?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to put an h1 next to a mat-form-field (from angular material) but I am struggling with that.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="greet($event)">
      <mat-option value="none">None</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="lime">Lime</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="red">Red</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="yellow">Yellow</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

<h1>{{products.length}} Telefonnummern</h1>

...

</div>
```

[image]

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

I didn't touch the css yet, I think it is an html problem.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: use style display:flex on parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this styles to your component css file:

```
mat-form-field{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
H1{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this css

```
.mat-elevation-z8 {    
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;    
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some details?

Answer (score -2):

You can use flex property on `div` like this

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" #yearSelect2>
      <mat-option value="none">None</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="lime">Lime</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="red">Red</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="yellow">Yellow</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

<h1>Telefonnummern</h1>

...

</div>
```